# DatePicker Issue in WPF, selects only current date

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datepicker

I am building a WPF application using C# in visual studio 2010 in .NET4. I have placed 2 datePickers on the window to select two different dates (or same dates). When I try to fetch the selected dates, I get the same date from both the datePickers, whatever the case may be, both of them return the current date.

[image: Error Image, Selected dates are different but both return the same date.]

Please help me.Am I missing something?

```
datePicker1.DisplayDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Edit: The DisplayDate property is also fixed to today's date. Why? How can I remove it?

Comment: how do you read the selected dates from the datapickers. Provide your code

Comment: Should I rather use datePicker1.SelectedDate.ToString(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could post your code, but all you need shoud be something like:

```
DateTime date = datePickerDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
```

depending on the type of validation you also want to provide regarding nulls, for instance (you can just use .SelectedDate or SelectedDate.Value dependind on the types you want)